# Communication tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I think a [communication](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) tag could be of use on this site. By "communication" I mean the way of living things to "talk" to one another by producing sounds, making gestures or posing, whatever can be interpreted by another creature as a signal. As in animals, birds, bugs, insects and I guess that includes human speech too.